# How to hide Javascript method code in karate report

Tags: karate

I have many Javascript methods in a karate feature. Exact method with whole code is getting printed in the Karate report as Doc string. Is there a way that I can hide the code of the method in Karate report?

Comment: Done. Accepted Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the JS from a file.

Or you can hide steps from the report, read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity